Enforce generic type to the Typesript class only when it is given in class instantiation
I am currently refactoring a telemetry logger with two thoughts in mind:

I wish to give flexibility to the users so that they can pass in optional customData object.
If so, ensure that the set of properties in customData is identical whenever it's passed to the measure().

I have removed the implementation details to make this post concise.
TypeScript Playground
interface Measurements {
    duration: number;
    count: number;
}

export interface ICustomData<TKey extends string> {
    customData?: { readonly [key in TKey]: number };
}

interface LoggerData<TCustomDataKey extends string> extends ICustomData<TCustomDataKey> {
    measurements: Measurements;

    /**
     * Accumulates sums of `customData` provided.
     * Empty unless desire to use `customData`.
     */
    dataSums: { [key in TCustomDataKey]?: number };


    /**
     * Stores maxes of `customData` provided. 
     * Empty unless desire to use `customData`. 
     */

    dataMaxes: { [key in TCustomDataKey]?: number };
}

/**
 * Main class `TelemetryLogger` which will be used for example.
 * A large chunk of the implementation has been removed for concision. 
 */
export class TelemetryLogger<TCustomMetrics extends string> {

    private readonly measurementsMap = new Map<string, LoggerData<TCustomMetrics>>();

    public measure<T = TCustomMetrics extends string ? ICustomData<TCustomMetrics> : void>(
        codeToMeasure: () => T,
    ): T {
        const returnValue = codeToMeasure();

        return returnValue;
    }
}

/**
 * Requirements
 * 1. If no intention of using `customData`, generic type is NOT given when instatiating the `LoggerData` class.
 * 2. Otherwise, a SPECIFIC set of strings must be provided during class instantiation. 
 */

interface IDummyData {
    foo: number
    bar: number
}

// A type is given during the instantiation. 
// Therefore, the `measure()` should only accept and return object of:
// {    customData : {  foo: 1, bar: 2  }   }
const loggerOne = new TelemetryLogger<keyof IDummyData>()

// This should work
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        customData: {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2,
        }
    }
})

// This should NOT work
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        customData: {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2,
            bazz: 3
        }
    }
})

// This should NOT work
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        
    }
})

// This should NOT work
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        bazz: 3
        
    }
})

// Generic type not given.
const loggerTwo = new TelemetryLogger()

// This should work
loggerTwo.measure(() => {})

// This should NOT work
loggerTwo.measure(() => {
    return {
        customData: {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2
        }
    }
})

// This should NOT work
loggerTwo.measure(() => {
    return {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2
    }
})

I first tried type generics such as:
-
measure<T = TCustomMetrics extends string ? ICustomData<TCustomMetrics>



export class TelemetryLogger<TCustomMetrics extends string = never> & public measure<T extends ICustomData<TCustomMetrics>>(codeToMeasure: () => T): T;



But none of the options worked.

You have multiple essentially unrelated issues here; please [edit] to make it have only one. For example: you cannot easily reject extra properties returned from a function. (See ms/TS#241 and this SO q). I doubt you really want to ask about this per se, since it's a pervasive TS thing and not really going to help with your conditional type checking code. So please remove that example so nobody fights with it. There are more, that's just one.

I'm seeing a number of problems.
First, the use of the generic <T> in measure<T> is always getting inferred implicitly. Since you are returning T in the parameter, typescript will always infer T and reflect it back to you.
function foo<T = 2>(bar: () => T): T {
    return bar()
}

const a = foo(() => 2) // => number
const b = foo(() => 3) // => number
const c = foo(() => {}) // => void
const d = foo(() => 'uhoh') // => string

We'll need to remove the generic from the method & use just the types in the class. We can even use generic types but not a generic method.
type TMeasureResult<TCustomMetrics extends string> =
  TCustomMetrics extends string ? ICustomData<TCustomMetrics> : void

export class TelemetryLogger<TCustomMetrics extends string> {
    public measure(codeToMeasure: () => TMeasureResult<TCustomMetrics>): TMeasureResult<TCustomMetrics> {
        const returnValue = codeToMeasure();

        return returnValue;
    }
}

const loggerOne = new TelemetryLogger<keyof IDummyData>()

// Works
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        customData: {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2,
        }
    }
})

// Does not compile
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        
    }
})


Second, TCustomMetrics always extends string, even if T is a constant or a union of constants. So TCustomMetrics extends string ? ICustomData<TCustomMetrics> : void will never resolve to void. You may want to change to lass TelemetryLogger<TCustomMetrics extends string | void> and refactor.

Third, annotating a function with () => void does not prevent return values.
type VoidFn = () => void

// These both work
const foo: VoidFn = () => {}
const bar: VoidFn = () => 2

A type of () => undefined might be a better fit
type UndefinedFn = () => undefined

// Works
const foo: UndefinedFn = () => {}

// Compile error
const bar: UndefinedFn = () => 2


Lastly & possibly most problematic, keyof IDummyData resolves to 'foo' | 'bar'.
Since unions get distributed, ICustomData<'foo' | 'bar'> resolves to ICustomerData<'foo'> | ICustomerData<'bar'>.
So TelemetryLogger<'foo' | 'bar'>['measure'] will return type ICustomerData<'foo'> | ICustomerData<'bar'>, meaning either { foo } or { bar } will satisfy the type.
// Does not compile, has neither keys `foo` nor `bar`
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        customData: {}
    }
})

// Does compile, satisfies with key `foo`
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        customData: {
            foo: 1,
        }
    }
})

// Also compiles, satisfies with key `bar`
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        customData: {
            bar: 2,
        }
    }
})

// Also compiles, extra keys are still valid
loggerOne.measure(() => {
    return {
        customData: {
            foo: 1,
            baaazzzz: 3,
        }
    }
})

If you want to get the exact shape of ICustomerData, you'll want to use that type as the generic.

TL;DR: leading us finally to something like this.
export interface ICustomData<T> {
    customData: T
}

type TMeasureResult<TCustomMetrics> = TCustomMetrics extends void ? undefined : ICustomData<TCustomMetrics>

export class TelemetryLogger<TCustomMetrics = void> {

    public measure(
        codeToMeasure: () => TMeasureResult<TCustomMetrics>,
    ): TMeasureResult<TCustomMetrics> {
        const returnValue = codeToMeasure();

        return returnValue;
    }
}

Hope that helps. Good luck.

"casting a function" there's no casting in your examples. Maybe you mean annotating?

@jcalz I do indeed. Fixed up.
